# Puppet -- Mount with Bind

Tags: puppet

I have a cluster of 500 linux boxes which now need to use the mount resource with the bind option (see man 8 mount) to support a chroot jail. The mount points need to be enforced and maintained after boot. I am unsure how to describe this state with puppet. Is it like this?

```
mount { "/gpfs20/home":
  ensure  => mounted,
  name    => "/chroot/centos5/home",
  fstype  => "none",
  options => "(rw,bind)",
}
```

TIA  -- Charles

Comment: Would you be better posting this on Server Fault or Unix & linux StackExchange sites?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For the record it is done this way:

```
mount { '/chroot/centos5/home': 
  ensure  => mounted, 
  device  => '/gpfs20/home', 
  fstype  => 'none', 
  options => 'rw,bind', 
}
```

~Charles~